# I'm making a Discordjs bot and want to be able to update code without making bot go offline

Tags: javascript, raspberry-pi, discord, discord.js

I'm building a Discord bot and when I add commands I want to be able to update the bot without taking it offline. I host this bot on a Raspberry Pi. I don't want it to go offline for a few reasons. The main reason is I have a cooldown system for a command and if the bot resets so does the cooldown and the users then can spam the command. I have tried  the Discord.js Guide Reloading commands suggestion (https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/adding-features.html#reloading-commands) but never seemed to work for me since that was for only pre existing commands. Any suggestions and help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the cooldown issue use a database like [Enmap](https://npmjs.com/package/enmap).

If you want to reload added commands, you *must* be using a command handler.

Just re-run your command handler's setup code to add and remove commands (usually looks like a `fs.readdir` call which handles each command)